# Equivalent of django-tables2 for Pyramid?

Tags: python, django, pyramid, django-tables2

Is there a Pyramid equivalent for [django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2)? I find this library really awesome... almost perfect I would say, and I am trying to find an equivalent now that I switched to Pyramid.

Comment: To be honest, I am finally doing this on the client side, using datatables and ajax by serving json.

Answer (score 0):

About 3 years ago I've commited this grid plugin, it works with various data types - it has support for sorting, and is very configurable.

http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/WebHelpers/modules/html/grid.html

I'm unaware of any other packages than mine.